# How to get created_at date only not time in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the `created_at` **date** of a user only but it is also fetching the **time**. Code:

```
{{{ isset(Auth::user()->created_at) ? Auth::user()->created_at : Auth::user()->email }}}
```

Results: 2017-05-09 11:44:09

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`toDateString()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

```php
{{ isset(Auth::user()->created_at) ? Auth::user()->created_at->toDateString() : Auth::user()->email }}
```

or `format()`

```php
{{ isset(Auth::user()->created_at) ? Auth::user()->created_at->format('m/d/Y') : Auth::user()->email }}
```

Comment: `format()` option worked nice for me, also it can be used to extract time, i.e- `Auth::user()->created_at->format(h:i:s A)`

Answer (score 16):

I have some more solutions:

```
where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'));
```

```
whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

```
whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

It will work 100%

Answer (score -1):

$query->where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromDate)).' 00:00:00')->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($toDate)).' 23:59:59');

This will work for sure.

Comment: Hi Ankit, thank you for your time and contribution. I kindly request you to enhance the content and structure of your answer and consider using code blocks.